# FFMPEG hwaccel complex filters

Tags: ffmpeg

I know this can be done by simply removing -hwaccel cuvid BUT I was wondering how this hwuplaod / hwdownload complex filtering stuff actually works with ffmpeg.

```
T:\ffmpeg\bin\20181015-c27c7b4-win64-static\ffmpeg.exe -y -loglevel 48 -hwaccel_device 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i "input.mp4" -i "watermark.png" -filter_complex "format=nv12,hwupload,overlay=0:0" -b:v 24000k -c:v h264_nvenc -c:a copy "output.mp4"

Parsed_format_0 @ 00000250b79758c0] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scaler_0' between the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'Parsed_format_0'
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
```

This results in the errors above, however removing the -hwaccel_device 0 and -hwaccel cuvid allows ffmpeg to run and export as expected, however GPU (gtx1080ti) usage is only at about 25% and my cpu (i9-7900x sits around 80%). There is obviously a better way to work this.

Comment: The regular overlay filter is s/w so it can't be part of an h/w only pipeline.

Comment: well thats a bit disappointing lol. do you know of another way to achieve something similar via hardware accelerated means only?